# Create a table dynamically , number of row depend of select number

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i am a beginner in jquery...  sorry

I need to create dynamically a table depending of the number of rows i choose by a

---

index.php

```
<div class="input-append" >
<span class="add-on">Nombre de TGBT</span>
 <?
$selected = '';
echo '<select name="nb_tgbt"  id="nb_tgbt" size="1">',"\n";
for($i=0; $i<=10; $i++)
{
$selected = 'selected="selected"';
echo "\t",'<option value="'.$i.'"'.$selected.'>'.$i.'</option>',"\n";
$selected='';
 }
echo '</select>',"\n";       
?>
 </div>
```

---

i send the value by POST method to a page "getvalue.php"

code of the getvalue.php is:

```
<?php

$tabletgbt='';
$tabletgbt=$tabletgbt.'<form>
                         <fieldset> 
                             <div class="input-append">';

for($i=1; $i<=$_POST['id']; $i++)
{
$tabletgbt=$tabletgbt.'<div><span class="add-on">Nom TGBT'.$i.'</span>       
<input  id="tgbtname'.$i.'" type="text" placeholder="Nom du TGBT '.$i.'"/>  

</div>';
}

$tabletgbt=$tabletgbt.'
                           </div>
                     </fieldset>
                   </form>';
return $tabletgbt;



$i='';
?>
```

---

How can i show the return data (html code) on my index.php dynamically on  change please

Regards

Comment: I don't see any code that's using AJAX, are you asking us how to us AJAX as well?

Comment: ^ Please add that into your question OP - large chunks of code aren't very readable in comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the ajax code i used:

```
Hello,  this is the ajax code i used:
   <script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#nb_tgbt').change(function(){ 
    var nbretgbt_id = $('#nb_tgbt').val(); 
    if(nbretgbt_id != 0) { 
    $.ajax({ type:'post', url:'getvalue.php', data:{id:nbretgbt_id}, cache:false, success: function(returndata){
  $('#tablename_tgbt').html(returndata); 
    } 
});
} 
}) 
}) 
</script>
```